# safari and chrome javascript console multiline

Tags: javascript, browser, debugging

Firebug has a multiline feature in their console tool. Is there a way to get this functionality with the debugger tool in Safari/Chrome?

Comment: You can use a chrome extension called "BigConsole", i find it very handy.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Shift-Enter on Windows allows multi-line entry where Option-Enter works on Mac.

A more fully featured editor is in the works.

Comment: Ctrl-Enter and Shift-Enter also work (for me!) on Mac OS (I'm using Chrome 14; can't vouch for earlier versions.) Also, pasting in multi-line code 'just works'. To run multi-line code, press Enter.

Answer (score 30):

For `Google Chrome`, you can `Sources >> Snippets >> + New Snippet` in the `Developer Console`.

[image]

Once you have written your `multi-line code`, you can execute it with the  [image] `button` or with `Ctrl + Enter` as mentioned on the `button`.

This is like a text-editor which has a host of `keyboard shortcuts` which you can find under `Settings >> Shortcuts` under `Text Editor`

[image]

Good Luck.

Answer (score 17):

I recommend this:

1. Write `debugger;` and hit *Enter*, in the console tab
2. This takes you to the **Sources** tab; if not, make sure debugger breakpoints are active
3. Now you can write whatever you want in the **Sources** tab, which acts like a full IDE with features like newline and indentation
4. Select any part of your code to run, and right-click, choose `Evaluate in console`

Comment: That's cool, thanks. Is there a keyboard shortcut for 'Evaluate in console'?

Answer (score 12):

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35487

Not yet.

**UPDATE**: the status of the issue I linked to is now "fixed".

Comment: For those who might only read this answer: multi-line console entry is now possible in the Chrome dev tools, as per MrBester's answer below.

Comment: imho - the snippets feature is the best way to handle this:  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/authoring-development-workflow#snippets  - plus you get the added benefit of creating lots of them and reusing them.

Answer (score 11):

Try pressing option (shift on Windows) at the same time as return. Inserts a newline on Mac.

Answer (score 5):

Shift + Enter seems to work in chrome browser. I am using ubuntu 12.04 as my operating system. Thanks to Mr Bester and Sam Dutton for their inputs.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple ... place semicolons between your multilines and it will work in the console.

For example

if you have html like this

```
<div id="test">This is a test statement</div>
```

You could paste following in the console and it will work

```
var ourTest = document.getElementById('test'); alert(ourTest.innerHTML);
```

I hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

There is cool extension to chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bigconsole/klommbdmeefgobphaflhmnieheipjajm

It just add another tab named BigConsole and it allow multiline code execution

Answer (score -4):

Try using the notepad (or someting else) and then copy/paste to the console, works for me!!!!